# Есть ли оператор декремента в шаблонах django

Tags: django

Нужно в шаблоне `href="?page={{ page }}`, уменьшить значение переменной page на единицу. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать фильтр [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{{ page|add:'-1' }}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как здесь же изменить значение этой переменной в зависимости от некоторого условия?

Comment: Например какого условия?

Comment: например if page==1: page-=1 else: page=5

Comment: `{% page == 1 %}{{ page|add:'-1' }}{% else %}5{% endif %}`

Comment: спасибо огромное, попробую